# IMPORTXML: is this xpath_query correct?

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I'd like to know if the following formula is correct?

> =IMPORTXML("http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/ImbalanceNrvPrice.v1.svc/GetImbalanceNrvPrices?day=2014-04-14","//PNeg")

It gives an error `#N/A` but some googling teaches me that the `importxml` is a fickle thing. It should import a list of 24 values, starting with `57.48`, but since I get an error I just want to be sure that the problem is caused by the function and not by my  xpath_query being wrong, because this is the first time I tried something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
=transpose(regexextract(importdata("http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/ImbalanceNrvPrice.v1.svc/GetImbalanceNrvPrices?day=2014-04-14"),rept("<PNeg>(.*)<\/PNeg>.*",96)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to parse all file with"

```
//*
```

and Your selector:

```
//PNeg
```

must work, but [there is error in Column: 190 Error: Can not find declaration of element 'ImbalanceNrvPriceResponse'.](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/?lang=en&url=http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/ImbalanceNrvPrice.v1.svc/GetImbalanceNrvPrices%3fday=2014-04-14) - probably that's the reason.